# Insert Double In Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 and C#. 
I'm declaring a variable of type `double` and i want to insert it in my database. I have this error:

> data type conversion error varchar to numeric.

How could i insert a value of type double in SQL Server using C#?

This is the Code:

```
double variable = 13.2;

con.Open();
cmd=con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "insert into etudient (IDetudient, [nom etudient], value) values('" + Convert.ToInt16( text_id.Text) + "' , '" + text_name.Text + "','" + variable + "')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
 MessageBox.Show("success");
```

Comment: Leave the quotes around your number data. They are not a strings.

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This code is wide open to sql injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, *variable* is of type `double` which is not a string, so you should be inserting the *variable* in this format:

`" + variable + "` and not `'" + variable + "'`

Further, your `Insert` query goes like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into etudient (IDetudient, [nom etudient], value)
    values('" + Convert.ToInt16( text_id.Text) + "' , '" + text_name.Text + "'," + variable + " )";
```

It is infact, recommended to use [**Parameterized Queries**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) as it prevents *SQL Injection Attacks*.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
        @"INSERT INTO etudient (IDetudient, [nom etudient], value)
          VALUES (@ID, @Name, @Variable)", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", text_id.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", text_name.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Variable", variable);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much Brother
I tried it and it's work 
Thank you so much .. may Allah blesses your knowledge :-)

Answer (score 0):

Erase the ' before and after variable...

If you put variable between ', you are saying it is text, that's why the error says it can't convert varchar to numeric.